# Could not find endpoint element with name '' and contract '' in the ServiceModel client configuration section

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, sharepoint

I have tried days to solve this damn error. I am calling the same service in asp.net and it works fine, but when I call it in a sharepoint solution it does not work. This is the error that I receive.

```
Could not find endpoint element with name 'WeatherSoap' and contract 'WeatherService.WeatherSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.
```

this is my app.config in the library:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WeatherSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="WeatherSoap12">
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </textMessageEncoding>
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WeatherSoap"
            contract="WeatherService.WeatherSoap" name="WeatherSoap" />
        <endpoint address="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WeatherSoap12"
            contract="WeatherService.WeatherSoap" name="WeatherSoap12" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is my C# code

```
WeatherService.WeatherSoapClient client = new WeatherService.WeatherSoapClient("WeatherSoap");
 WeatherService.WeatherReturn result = client.GetCityWeatherByZIP(txtZip.Text);
```

this is the code that I use in code behind in both sharepoint visual web part and in asp.net web page. The strange thing is that it works fine in asp.net but not in sharepoint.
I'm calling the service in a same project.

Comment: Is the sharepoint visual web part a part of the asp.net website? From the error, it appears that the configuration file of the application (not the library where you are calling the service) does not have the required information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647110.aspx

You may need to add configure the wcf endpoint programmatically for the sharepoint web part.